# Can Visual Studio generate C# code instead of XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I love XAML and everything, but how can I make Visual Studio generate C# code instead?

This is for learning purposes, just to see how the compiler translates from XAML to C#.

Thank you!

Comment: Simple, don't use WPF.  I'm not trying to be snarky or sarcastic, but that's the only option that you have (unless there is a third-party plugin that I'm unaware of.)

Comment: I actually have nothing against XAML. As I stated, I want to see C# code for learning purposes only. I will still use XAML for my projects though.

Answer (score 4):

I have written this tool which generates equivalent c# code for the xaml provided.

http://xamlgenerator.codeplex.com/

Comment: That's awesome, I will definitely check it out!

Comment: @akash It is incompatible with VS 2013. Any new releases?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will create partial classes for your XAML to give you access to your identifiers in the code behind (look in /obj/Debug/*.g.cs, etc), but most of it is converted to a binary resource representation (BAML) which is then loaded at run time, not converted to MSIL.

Comment: Thank you, I did not even know about those files. They indeed contain Main and identifiers - at least something:)

Comment: Keep in mind that the .g files are **not** C# translations of XAML.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but it's at least something:)

Answer (score 0):

Such a feature does not exist, and although you could write a plugin to achieve this behavior, such a plugin does not (yet) exist either. MSDN does a pretty good job of showing both XAML and C# representations of features.

Comment: I hope someone will come up with it soon. Seems like a useful tool to have!